# Eros incident casualty count in The Expanse

Tags: the-expanse

The books state that the entire population of Eros, at 1.5 million was wiped out in the Eros incident. However in the TV show, they repeatedly keep saying a hundred thousand. Anyone noticed this and knows why they might've wanted to tone down the severity of the incident?

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV!

Comment: This question is very close to only being answerable by word of god, which is off-topic as it is nigh impossible to expect whoever made that story decision to actually be an active user of Movies.SE.